# What is the format of the airport codes used in an ACARS OOOI message?

Tags: flight-planning, acars

How are the departure and arrival airport codes in the OUT, OFF, ON and IN (OOOI) fields identified by ACARS and transmitted to ground systems?

For example, if my aircraft is diverted unexpectedly to Bangkok because of some emergency, will ACARS send the arrival airport code as BKK in the IN message? If so, how will it be identified?

Comment: I'm looking forward to an answer that includes definitions of OOOI. I mean, I get the _Out, Off, On, In_ but what does it all mean???

Comment: @FreeMan *"OOOI
(Out of the gate, Off the ground, On the ground, 
and Into the gate messages): Pushback from gate, 
wheels off, wheels on, arrival time at the gate, number 
of passengers, wheel chairs required, etc."*

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - thank you sir! OOOI is certainly much shorter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ACARS messages, unsurprisingly, use IATA airport codes.

See ARINC 618, 619, 620 etc.

[image]
[image]

- [ACARS, Dr. Maarten Uijt de Haag, Ohio University](http://www.ohio.edu/people/uijtdeha/ee6900_fms_08_acars.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. So the ACARS automatically detects the airport code and appends with **IN to the Gate** Acars message?